# Clojure : loading dependencies at the REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I recently learned (thanks to technomancy) that, at the REPL ---

**This fails:**

```
user=> (:require [clojure.set :as set])
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.set (NO_SOURCE_FILE:24)
```

**Whereas this succeeds :**

```
user=> (require '[clojure.set :as cs]) 
nil
```

at loading the clojure.set class.

Context: *The former line was copied from a namespaced source file.*

My primary question is : **What is the change we have made, by swapping the  : and ' characters, which now allows for success of the latter command ?**

My 2nd question is , **in general - what are the guidelines for doing things at the REPL --- as compared with doing things in normal clojure source files ?** Assume here that we can load our repl from the root of a LEININGEN project, so at least the jars will be available on disk in the dependencies sub directory.

Comment: I guess this realy asks the question of "why require is a keyword in a normal clj file --- but a standard function at the REPL".

Comment: I think the second part is a bit general and should be removed or split into a totally separate post.

Answer (score 59):

I'll go from high-level down to your particular problem:

## How Clojure (or LISPs) Generally Work

REPLs, or Read-Eval-Print Loops are the core of how LISPs are designed:

- The **reader** converts a stream of characters into data structures (called Reader Forms).
- The **evaluator** takes collection of reader forms and evaluates them.
- The **printer** emits the results of the evaluator.

So when you enter text into a REPL, it goes through each of these steps to process your input and return the output to your terminal.

## Reader Forms

First some, clojure reader forms. This will be extremely brief, I encourage you to [read](http://clojure.org/reader) or watch ([part 1](https://youtu.be/ketJlzX-254?list=PLZdCLR02grLrEwKaZv-5QbUzK0zGKOOcr), [part 2](https://youtu.be/sp2Zv7KFQQ0?list=PLZdCLR02grLrEwKaZv-5QbUzK0zGKOOcr)) about it.

A **symbol** in clojure is form that can represent a particular value (like a variable).  Symbols themselves can be pass around as data. They are similar to pointers in c, just without the memory management stuff.

A symbol with a colon in front of it is a **keyword**. Keywords are like symbols with the exception that a keyword's value are always themselves - similar to strings or numbers. They're identical to Ruby's symbols (which are also prefixed with colons).

A **quote** in front of a form tells the evaluator to leave the data structure as-is:

```
user=> (list 1 2)
(1 2)
user=> '(1 2)
(1 2)
user=> (= (list 1 2) '(1 2))
true
```

Although quoting can apply to more than just lists, it's primarily used for lists because clojure's evaluator will normally execute lists as a function-like invocation. Using the `'` is shorthand to the quote macro:

```
user=> (quote (1 2)) ; same as '(1 2)
(1 2)
```

Quoting basically specifies data structure to return and not actual code to execute. So you can quote symbols which refers to the symbol.

```
user=> 'foo ; not defined earlier
foo
```

And quoting is recursive. So all the data inside are quoted too:

```
user=> '(foo bar)
(foo bar)
```

To get the behavior of `(foo bar)` without quoting, you can eval it:

```
user=> (eval '(foo bar)) ; Remember, foo and bar weren't defined yet.
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
user=> (def foo identity)
#'user/foo
user=> (def bar 1)
#'user/bar
user=> (eval '(foo bar))
1
```

There's a lot more to quoting, but that's out of this scope.

## Requiring

As for require statements, I'm assuming you found the former in the form of:

```
(ns my.namespace
    (:require [clojure.set :as set]))
```

`ns` is a [macro](http://clojure.org/macros) that will transform the :require expression into the latter form you described:

```
(require '[clojure.set :as set])
```

Along with some namespacing work. The basics are described when asking for the docs of ns in the REPL.

```
user=> (doc ns)
-------------------------
clojure.core/ns
([name docstring? attr-map? references*])
Macro
  Sets *ns* to the namespace named by name (unevaluated), creating it
  if needed.  references can be zero or more of: (:refer-clojure ...)
  (:require ...) (:use ...) (:import ...) (:load ...) (:gen-class)
  with the syntax of refer-clojure/require/use/import/load/gen-class
  respectively, except the arguments are unevaluated and need not be
  quoted. (:gen-class ...), when supplied, defaults to :name
  corresponding to the ns name, :main true, :impl-ns same as ns, and
  :init-impl-ns true. All options of gen-class are
  supported. The :gen-class directive is ignored when not
  compiling. If :gen-class is not supplied, when compiled only an
  nsname__init.class will be generated. If :refer-clojure is not used, a
  default (refer 'clojure) is used.  Use of ns is preferred to
  individual calls to in-ns/require/use/import:
```

### REPL usage

In general, don't use `ns` in the REPL, and just use the `require` and `use` functions. But in files, use the `ns` macro to do those stuff.

Answer (score 16):

The difference is that `require` is a function used for importing code, whereas `:require` is a keyword.

Remember what happens when you use a keyword as a function:

```
=> (type :require)
clojure.lang.Keyword
=> (:require {:abc 1 :require 14})
14
```

it looks itself up in the map.  So when you pass `[clojure.set :as set]` to a keyword, it's trying to evaluate that to a vector, and fails because it doesn't know what `clojure.set` is.  The [Clojure docs](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-Keywords) say:

> Keywords implement IFn for invoke() of one argument (a map) with an
>   optional second argument (a default value). For example (:mykey
>   my-hash-map :none) means the same as (get my-hash-map :mykey :none).

You may have been confused by [the `ns` macro](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns):

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [ancestors printf])
  (:require (clojure.contrib sql sql.tests))    ;; here's :require!
  (:use (my.lib this that))
  (:import (java.util Date Timer Random)
           (java.sql Connection Statement)))
```

Comment: Yes it seems that the OP looked at usage of :require and created mental equivalency to (require), which is understandable; and it probably came from looking at code that used the former; the difference of course being that the forms are (ns ...) vs (require ...)

Answer (score 2):

#### `ns` **macro**:

When you type:

```
(ns some-great-ns 
  :require my-form)
```

you use the `:require` **reference** in which you state what would you like to use from the given namespace. It is equivalent to writing:

```
(in-ns 'some-great-ns)
(require 'my-form)
```

Notice that in the `ns` form (unlike the `in-ns` function call), you don’t have to quote your symbol with `'`. You never have to quote symbols within `ns`.

#### `require` function

As stated, can run: `(require 'some-great-ns)` in some given namespace so you could use it. To use it, you'll have to use full qualified name, unless you also use: `refer` function: `(refer 'some-great-ns)` right after you required the namespace.

You can do those both functions in one: `(use 'some-great-ns)`. Now you don't need to write: `(some-great-ns/my-form`). Simply: `my-form`.

And of course you can also use the `:as`, `:exclude`, `:only` and `:rename` keywords in both the macro reference and in the function.

#### Differences between the macro and the function:

1. As stated above, usage of symbols in function, no need in the macro
2. You can require multiple libraries in a `(:require)` reference as follows:

```
(ns my-great-namespace.core
  (:require [some-other-ns.a.b :as ab]
            [some-other-other-ns.c.d :as cd]))
```

Where in `function` writing you should write 2 lines:

```
(in-ns my-great-namespace.core)
(require 'some-other-ns.a.b :as 'ab)
(require 'some-other-other=ns.c.d :as 'cd)
```

3. The `require` reference also allows you to refer names, for example:

```
(ns my-great-namespace.core
  (:require [some-other-ns.a.b :refer [some-func]]))
```

Where in function you should do:

```
(in-ns my-great-namespace.core)
(require 'some-other-ns.a.b)
(refer 'some-other-ns.a.b :only ['some-func])
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it, but what does this add over [Jeff's highly-upvoted answer from almost a decade ago?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9811346/3757232).

Comment: @JaredSmith - Added some comparison between the macro and the function to point the difference between them.