# ClassNotFoundException on use of another ns

Tags: clojure, counterclockwise

As simple as this question is, I can't seem to find the right way for different namespaces in the same directory to validly refer to one another.   I have two files:

`project_root/src/babbler/core.clj`:

```
(ns babbler.core
  (:gen-class)
  (use '[clojure.string :only (join split)]))

(defn foo [] "Foo")
```

and then `project_root/src/babbler/bar.clj`:

```
(ns babbler.bar)

(use [babbler.core :as babble])
```

This file also contains a main method, which is specified in my `project.clj` via `:main babbler.bar`

My entire structure is that generated by counterclockwise, with with default leiningen template.

The result of running `lein repl` is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: babbler.core, compiling:(babbler/bar.clj:3:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6380)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$VectorExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3024)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6363)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
```

(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `use` should be inside the definition of the namespace:

```
(ns babbler.bar
  (use [babbler.core :as babble]))
```

In fact `use` is discouraged, you may want to write it as:

```
(ns babbler.bar
  (:require [babbler.core :as babble :refer [foo]]))
```

That way you can call any function f from the babbler.core namespace as babble/f, and you can call foo directly. In addition, your file has information about where foo comes from so you or someone else won't need to go searching for it.

Comment: This (using your :require syntax) seems to result in the different error:  Exception lib names inside prefix lists must not contain periods.   Why would that be?

Comment: in core, you need `(:require [clojure.string :refer [join split]])`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810841/clojure-loading-dependencies-at-the-repl