# Can't find clojure.set in ClojureClr

Tags: clojure, clojureclr

I am using `ClojureClr 1.6.0` and I'm trying to use `clojure.set` but I can't find it:

```
user=> (doc clojure.set/union)
; nil
```

When I try to use it, I get:

```
user=> (clojure.set/union #{1 2} #{3})
; TypeNotFoundException Unable to find type: clojure.set clojure.lang.RT.classForNameE (:0)
```

I tried to load it

```
user=> (require '(clojure.set))
; nil
```

but still couldn't find it.

Comment: Not finding the documentation is not the same as not finding the package. What happens when you actually use `clojure.set/union`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: @OrlandoWilliam How are you starting your REPL session?

Comment: I just run Clojure.Main.exe

Comment: Nil is the expected response. Have you tried using sets after running ```(require '(clojure.set))```?

Comment: yes, and still get the same `TypeNotFoundException`

Comment: Are you sure your syntax for loading the required dependencies is correct? I have 1.5.x, not 1.6, but both `(require 'clojure.set)` (note absence of parentheses around `clojure.set`) and `(require '[clojure.set :as cs])` (give it an alias) work for me. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810841/clojure-loading-dependencies-at-the-repl

Comment: @shoover, yes, yes, thank you, it works! please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for loading the required dependencies appears to be incorrect. I have 1.5.x, not 1.6, but both `(require 'clojure.set)` (note absence of parentheses around clojure.set) and `(require '[clojure.set :as cs])` (give it an alias) work for me. See also [Clojure : loading dependencies at the REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810841/clojure-loading-dependencies-at-the-repl)